# Why are newline characters stored in Android SQLite database not shown in TextView?

Tags: android

my App is reading insert sql, using BufferReader.readLine().

```
my sql is like this:
INSERT INTO TBL_EXAMPLE (COL_A, COL_B, COL_C) VALUES('1', '2', '- THIS IS EXAMPLE.\n- THIS IS EXAMPLE.');

and output that I want:
- THIS IS EXAMPLE.
- THIS IS EXAMPLE.
```

but, actual output is : 
- THIS IS EXAMPLE.\n- THIS IS EXAMPLE.

:(

I don't know why new_line character("\n") is not work.

how can I do that? I should be very grateful to you if you might help me :) (Sorry for short English, because I'm foreigner :| )

here is my code:

```
InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.db);

    try{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "EUC_KR"));

        while(true){

            String sql = br.readLine();
            if(sql!=null){
                db.execSQL(sql); // INSERT INTO TBL_EXAMPLE (COL_A, COL_B, COL_C) VALUES('1', '2', '- THIS IS EXAMPLE.\n- THIS IS EXAMPLE.');

            } else{
                break;
            }

        }
        is.close();
```

Comment: It's not about storing, it's about using the string afterwards. Where do you use/output it? TextView?

Comment: Yes, use in TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Html.fromHtml` to support new lines:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("- THIS IS EXAMPLE.<br/>- THIS IS EXAMPLE."));
```

Comment: Please beware that this will open you up to a lot of HTML injection problems and formatting issues, if you are not using a proper `Text -> HTML` conversion/escaping.